# How to read from the file java

Tags: java, grid

I am creating the grid so first, I have to input the size of the grid like 4 and then input the grid

```
0 0 0 1
1 2 3 0
2 2 0 2
3 3 1 0
```

however, I want to read the grid from the file.
For example, java test 4 < file.txt

Any suggestion on how to do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scn.nextInt(); 
    int[][] grid = new int[n][n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = scn.nextInt();
        }
    }
    int[][] dp = new int[n][n]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        dp[n - 1][j] = grid[n - 1][j];
    }
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < n) { 
                dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i + 1][j + 1], dp[i + 1][j - 1]) + grid[i][j];
            } else if (j - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= n) { 
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j - 1] + grid[i][j];
            } else { 
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j + 1] + grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    int ans = 0; 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        ans = Math.max(ans, dp[0][j]); 
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read from a file, you need to have the entire path (where it is located) so that you can read it. Assuming its from the directory as the jar, use can use the below code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    try {
     Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n = scn.nextInt();
     String fileName = scn.nextLine();
     File file= new File(fileName);
     Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
     while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
      int[][] grid = new int[n][n]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
              grid[i][j] = scn.nextInt();
          }
      }
     }
     //Remaining operation as in your code
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.printlin("Exception occurred while processing: " + e);
   }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Something similar can be used, I'm currently not having an editor with me, hence apologies for any mistakes

Comment: it does not work I have an error Exception occurred while processing: java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: also i go this error Exception occurred while processing: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  49 14  (No such file or directory) in print two number from grid 49 14

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int[][] grid = new int[n][n];
        File myObj = new File(args[2]);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] strs = myReader.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strs[j]);
            }
        }
        int[][] dp = new int[n][n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            dp[n - 1][j] = grid[n - 1][j];
        }
        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < n) {
                    dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i + 1][j + 1], dp[i + 1][j - 1]) + grid[i][j];
                } else if (j - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= n) {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j - 1] + grid[i][j];
                } else {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j + 1] + grid[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        int ans = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            ans = Math.max(ans, dp[0][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I am running this code like this java hello 3 < digger3_input.txt I am getting an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
        at hello.main(hello.java:10)

Comment: Now i have this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at hello.main(hello.java:8)

Comment: java hello 3 < digger3_input.txt should work

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work the errors says this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
        at hello.main(hello.java:10)